# Внедрить в массив переменную после 10-го ключа PHP

Tags: php, массивы

Подскажите как возможно внедрить в массив переменную но только после 10-го ключа и с условием если в ключе содержится точка или запятая. Если точка или запятая отсутствует не принимать никаких действий.

```
$news = "содержание переменой";

$string = "Как День Победы стал главным праздником страны, 8 мая 2018. У каждого государства есть главное событие, вокруг которого строится...";

$arr = explode(" ", $string);

print_r($arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [array_splice](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-splice.php)

Вот пример для вашего предложения → 
[Пример](https://ideone.com/fbCLXZ)

```
$news = "содержание переменой";
$string = "Как День Победы стал главным праздником страны, 8 мая 2018.     У каждого государства есть главное событие, вокруг которого строится...";
$arr = explode(" ", $string);

array_splice($arr, 10, 0, [$news]);
print_r($arr);
```